# How can I disable IPv6 DNS in Windows 10?

Tags: networking, dns, ipv6

My proxy server (though ping for 300ms+) have IPv6 addresses. I usually use it.

So disable whole IPv6 is not a solution.

Auto detected IPv6 DNS annoys me for wrong/lacked/polluted records.

Windows seems love IPv6 DNS too much, it will not fallback to IPv4 DNS if IPv6 DNS fails. :(

Is there anyway to disable DNS only in IPv6, or let Windows use IPv4 DNS first?

(Here is China, Google DNS is not a solution...)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  Sometimes Windows 10 uses my ISPs IPv6 (how it is getting it I don't know, because I'm using a DHCP which does NOT pass IPv6 DNS) and sometimes it doesn't, but when it does it breaks my LAN DNS resolution of world visible IP addresses which makes the local server unreachable!